# Why am I getting a "name error" with this IF formula?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I'm trying to use this formula to output "Tie" when the result is a draw:

> `=IF(B6>C6,B6-C6,IF(C6>B6,C6-B6,”Tie”))`

Instead of giving me what I want, it gives me a "name" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the curly-quotes that I see displayed around "Tie" in your actual formula?

Comment: Yes... The quotes look off there...  Could also try this:  =IF(B6=C6,"Tie", ABS(B6-C6))

Answer (score 3):

As the comments point out the quotes around Tie are indeed the problem. If you use the following formula with the expected quotes your formula will no longer give you the `#NAME?` error:

`=IF(B6>C6,B6-C6,IF(C6>B6,C6-B6,"Tie"))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two IF's try: =IF(B6=C6,"Tie",ABS(B6-C6))